# Block POST data for certain sites

Tags: php, post

I have `page.php` which receives POST data, it's located in a known position. **How can I obtain the url** of each page that sends data to `page.php` via POST, or **how can I block/allow POST data from certain sites**?

Answer (score 4):

You can (although not reliably) get the URL of the referring page via `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. There are, however, a number of situations where this will be blank (most commonly when coming from an HTTPS site).

The only reliable way to limit which sites can cause a browser to submit data to your script which will be accepted is to implement protection against CSRF and stop *all* sites that are not your site.

Generate a random token. Store that token in a cookie or session. Store it in a hidden input in the form. When the form is submitted, check if the token in the form matches the token in the cookie/session. If it doesn't, then the form that submitted the data was not on your site.

---

> I use PayPal IPN, so I need to check if POST comes from PayPal

You're trying to solve this problem the wrong way.

Read [Paypal's IPN documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). They provide a means to determine if the event came from them or not.

> 1. PayPal HTTP POSTs your listener an IPN message that notifies you of an event.
> 2. Your listener returns an empty HTTP 200 response to PayPal.
> 3. Your listener HTTP POSTs the complete, unaltered message back to PayPal; the message must contain the same fields (in the same order)
>      as the original message and be encoded in the same way as the original
>      message.
> 4. PayPal sends a single word back - either VERIFIED (if the message matches the original) or INVALID (if the message does not match the
>      original).

Comment: But how can I block POST data?

Comment: You use an `if` statement, generate an error message and `exit`.

Comment: Yes but I need something that works everytime, HTTP_REFERER can not work

Comment: Quentin has explained the solution. There is no such thing as `HTTP_REFERER` that works everywhere! You should use CSRF strategy some way.

Comment: Well I tried it but it doesn't work for me, my provider is "bugged", so I need another way to do it

Comment: Your provider is bugged? Do you mean that you can't trust your hosting service? **Change your hosting provider** and stop trusting them with your business!

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the form is from a certain page by doing something like this:

In your form add a random hidden value, and save the value to the session along with a page:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['csfr_token'] = $randomValue; // Randomly generated string
$_SESSION['csfr_page_url'] = ; // URL of the current page
?>
<input type="hidden" name="csfr_token" value="<?php echo $randomValue; ?>" />
```

The above obviously only applies if you are using a form, if not then add the `csfr_token` to the post using whatever method you are using.

Then on your page that manages the post:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

if (isset($_SESSION['csfr_token']) && $_POST['csfr_token'] && $_SESSION['csfr_page_url'] && $_SESSION['csfr_token'] === $_POST['csfr_token'] && $_SESSION['csfr_page_url'] === 'the URL that you want to allow') {
    // Do your stuff
} else {
    // Post isnt valid   
}
```

**Update:**

I think the following question is related: [Verifying a Paypal transaction via POST information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9118422/2859624)

Comment: I can't edit code from the sender page... it's not mine, it comes from an external site

Comment: You should also check the existence of both array keys.

Comment: Thanks ComFreek. @user2758571 Well your very limited how you can do it then. I don't really understand though, why does an external site send a post to you?

Comment: @AdamRivers I use PayPal IPN, so I need to check if POST comes from PayPal